# the line code results in a type error, and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: javascript, discord.js

this code results in a type error, and I don't know how to fix it, please someone help

```
I defined the client like this:
const Discord = require("discord.js");;
require('dotenv/config')
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = process.env.TOKEN;
const configt = require("./config.json");
const firebase = require('firebase');
const FieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue;
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccount.json')
const owner = process.env.OWNER;


    db.collection('guilds').doc(message.guild.id).get().then((q) => {
        if (q.exists){
            prefix = q.data().prefix;
        }
    }).then(() => {
            
     if (message.channel.type == 'dm') return;
     if (!message.guild) return;
     if (!message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(configt.prefix.toLowerCase())) return;
     if (message.content.startsWith(`<@!${client.user.id}>`) ||message.content.startsWith(`<@${client.user.id}>`)) return;
     if (message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content
        .trim().slice(configt.prefix.length)
        .split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    try {
        const commandFile = require(`./commands/${command}.js`)
        commandFile.run(client, message, args);
    } catch (err) {
    console.error('Erro:' + err);
  }
    if (client.commands.get(command.slice(prefix.length))){
        let cmd = client.commands.get(command.slice(prefix.length));
        if (cmd){
            cmd.run(client, message, args, db)
        }
    }
        
    })
```

error:

> (node:24) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'get' of undefined
> at /home/container/index.js:72:25
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) (node:24)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
> error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
> without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
> with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise
> rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 8)

Comment: Can we see some more code? The `client.commands` is clearly undefined but we need more code to know why.

Comment: ready, I upgraded to a larger part

Comment: Please add the code from the place where you define the `client` variable.

Comment: Reading the Discord.js documentation there is no object called `commands`. Are you sure you are accessing the right object?

Comment: i changed the `commands` to `command` that is defined, and gave the same error

Comment: The `command` is not present as well. Here look for yourself. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client

Comment: so what do I do